# mysql join 1 table w/ 1 row and table w/ many rows

Tags: mysql, database

```
1st table           2nd table

---------------      ----------
|id|name|hours|      |id|phour|
---------------      ----------
|1 |samp|  7  |      |1 |  10 |
---------------      ----------
|2 |smp2|  1  |
```

Output

```
------------------
|phour|name|hours|
------------------
|  10 |samp|  7  |
------------------
|     |smp2|  1  |
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to include rows in the result when there's no match in the second table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: carpetsmoker because you didnt understand??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
select phour, name, hours from table1 right join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
```